# Getting the method of an Operation Object Swagger 2.0

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

This is probably a very simple question but I can't seem to figure it out. How do you get an Operations object's method with swagger 2.0?

From the transition guide: 
"The structure of most objects has changed (such as the Operation Object, the Parameter Object). Among other changes, in many cases instead of stating the type of the object, the property name directing to the object will state its type. For example, for operations, you would have a property name called "get" pointing to an Operation Object. As such, the method field is dropped from the object itself."

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/wiki/Swagger-1.2-to-2.0-Migration-Guide

So my question is if you had an operations object how would you get the method? Specifically in c#?

I'm trying to migrate my operation filters from 1.2 to 2.0

```
void IOperationFilter.Apply(Swashbuckle.Swagger.Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType == typeof(HttpResponseMessage))
            {
                switch (operation.Method)
                {
                    ...

                }
            }
```

But operation.Method is no longer available in swagger 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swagger 2.0 the structure of operation changes so it no longer has a property for the method type. So if you have the operation object you can't get the method, but the ApiDescription has an HttpMethod attribute that will indicate whether the operation is a Get, Put, Post or Delete. What was previously operation.Method can now be retrieved with

```
apiDescription.HttpMethod.ToString()
```